# jQuery hierarchy issue with next()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Seems like `$("img").next().hide();` is not working when both the image and div tag are a child of a paragraph.

```
<p>
<img src="image.jpg" />
<div>text</div> // this div is set to 'display: none' by default in css
</p>
```

Yet, if I substitute `<div>` with `<span>`

```
<p>
<img src="image.jpg" />
<span>text</span>
</p>
```

or if I omit the `<p>` tags

```
<img src="image.jpg" />
<div>text</div>
```

the jQuery selector does work properly. Any ideas why this is the case? Is it related to inline and block display? How can I make it work as described in the top code example?

This is the jQuery code I am using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img").hover(
        function()
        {
            $(this).next().show();
        },
        function()
        {
            $(this).next().hide();
        }
    );
});
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`p` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#edef-P) does only allow [inline-level elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/sgml/dtd.html#inline) as child elements. This may be the reason for why your first example does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use block element (DIV) inside inline elmenents (P). 
Instead of P use DIV with class set like P.